# Using the JavaScript this keyword

Tags: javascript

I know `this` refers to the `constructor` method but what does the line `this.tasks = tasks;` do?

```
class TaskCollection {
    constructor(tasks =[]) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: `tasks` is only a parameter. `this.tasks` is an accessible object property. You can’t get `tasks` from outside the constructed object, but you can access it with `obj.tasks` if you set `this.tasks` first.

Comment: "this" in the given context of a constructor actually refers to the class instance itself. Hence, through the use of "this" in the given context you can set the "task" properties of the instantiated objects of the class by passing in the necessary arguments to the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

That line assigns the tasks passed in through the constructor to the "tasks" member of the class instance.

Basically, you can do this:

```
collection = new TaskCollection([task1,task2]);
```

Now, you can access those tasks like this:

```
collection.tasks // [task1,task2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is the reserved word **Class** in javascript, function TaskCollection here defines the class, this code works fine in a jsfiddle but needs to define what is the array tasks, and also define what is the **constructor** reserved word

```
function TaskCollection (name, tasks) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tasks = tasks;
}

var collection = new TaskCollection('col', ['task1','task2']);
console.log(collection.name);
```